# Save each table column in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

For a jQuery plugin I need to add / remove classes to table columns. To do that I want to save each table column (multiple `<td>`) in its one variable once. The HTML for the table looks more or less like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In the end I want an array like `$tableColumn[]` or something, so that I can just add a class to my first column with `$tableColumn[ 0 ].addClass('test');`.

I could loop through each `<tr>` and `<td>`, but I'm not sure how to add multiple `td` to the same variable? Is there any other and better (e.g better performance) way to do that?

```
var $tableColumn = [];

$('table tr').each(function() {
    // Loop through all rows
    $( this ).find('td').each(function( idx ) {
        // If I do something like this, there's only one td in my array
        // Probably there is a better way to do this without needing to have two 'each' functions
        $tableColumn[ idx ] = $( this );
    });
});
```

Comment: Why don't you just save the `tr` and then add the class to its children. Probably be cleaner.

Comment: @Blunderfest I want to save the columns because I need to add / remove classes whenever to user interacts with the table. If I just save the `<tr>` elements I need to do something like `$tableRows.find('td')` every time I want to add a class to a column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of, why is there two table ? You don't need to have a table tag for each row.

For your question and since you use jquery you can try something like this : (by using CSS3 selector)

```
$('table tr td:nth-child(' +columnNumber +')').addClass( className )
```

The nth-child selector will effectively select the columnNumber child of each row (tr) and therefore `$('table tr td:nth-child(columnNumber)')` get the columnNumber-th column of the table.

jsBin : http://jsbin.com/qisosado/2/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Thanks, that should work... and sorry for the table markup. I'm not sure why there were `table` tags inside my `table`. Do you by chance know if it's faster to use nth-child (multiple times for each column) or two each functions for that kind of stuff? Or won't there be any difference at all?

Comment: nth-child ought to be faster in regard to the [test](http://jsperf.com/answer-to-question-25230477)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) to create an array of jQuery selections.

```
var i,
    columns = [],
    nColumns = $('table tr:first td').length;

for(i = 1; i <= nColumns; i ++) {
    columns.push($('td:nth-child(' + i + ')'));
}

columns[0].addClass('a');
columns[1].addClass('b');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gb0y0y6g/

Alternatively, check out the [col tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col).

Comment: Thanks, haven't heard of the `col` tag yet. Not sure if it works in my case though, since I need to add classes to the `td` (columns) directly in order to hide them (for smaller screens) and stuff like that.

Answer (score 1):

i have created a jsfiddle for you..

**for single column in row:-**
code:-

```
var tableColumn = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table tr td').each(function() {
        tableColumn.push($(this));
    });
    //access the td from the array
    tableColumn[0].addClass("yellow")

});
```

working example:-
http://jsfiddle.net/zoohcveh/12/

**for all columns in row:-**

code:-

```
var tableColumn = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table tr').each(function() {
        tableColumn.push($(this));
    });
    //access all the td from the array
    tableColumn[0].addClass("yellow")

});
```

working example:-http://jsfiddle.net/zoohcveh/13/
thanks

Comment: This only affects the first `td`, not every `td` in the first column.

Comment: you want to add class in whole row?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a column group if you're trying to do column specific things, like changing the background color of every cell in a column.

You can also use jQuery selectors to get a specific group of cells out of a collection.

jsbin: http://jsfiddle.net/pqm2gbqz/

HTML:

```
<button>Toggle</button>
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col />
        <col />
        <col />
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Column 1 row 2</td>
        <td>Column 2 row 2</td>
        <td>Column 3 row 2</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var colgroup = document.querySelectorAll('col'),
    button = document.querySelector('button'),
    $tds = $("table").find("td")
;


button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    colgroup.item(0).classList.toggle('some-class');

    $tds.filter(":last-of-type").toggleClass('hide');
});
```

CSS:

```
.some-class {
    background: green;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}
```